# prove that $f(z)=0$ , complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:\Bbb{C} \setminus \{0\}\to\Bbb{C}$ be a holomorphic function that satisfies $|f(z)|\le|z|^\frac{-3}{2}$ for all $z \in \Bbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$.

Prove that $f(z)=0$ for all $z \in \Bbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$.

Can anybody help me out, I can't really figure out a way to prove that. I think that $0$ is an essential singularity point, and it might have something to do with the function's Laurent series.

Any advice?

Comment: With such a growth condition, $0$ can't be an essential singularity, it can be at worst a pole of order $\lfloor 3/2\rfloor = 1$. It's maybe easier to see when you look at $g(z) = f(1/z)$ that $g$, and hence $f$ must vanish identically. Well, or you could also look at either of $h_1 \colon z \mapsto zf(z)$ or $h_2 \colon z \mapsto z^2 f(z)$.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer...Please elaborate how $g(z) vanishes identically?

Comment: @mathlover We have $\lvert g(z)\rvert \leqslant \lvert z\rvert^{3/2}$ for all $z\in \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$. So $g$ has a removable singularity at $0$, and considering that removed, $g$ has a zero of order at least $\lceil 3/2\rceil = 2$ at $0$. On the other hand, the growth condition at $\infty$ shows that $g$ is a polynomial of degree $\leqslant \lfloor 3/2\rfloor = 1$. A polynomial of degree $1$ has exactly one zero (counting multiplicities) in $\mathbb{C}$, so $g$ must be constant, and vanish identically since it vanishes at $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Daniel, consider the function $g(z)= z^2f(z)$. This function has a removable singularity at $z=0$, and satisfies $|g(z)| \leq \sqrt{|z|}$. It can now easily be shown thanks to Cauchy's formula that $g$ is constant, you have indeed the estimate, for all complex $z$, and all $r >|z|$ :

\begin{align*}
|g'(z)| &= \frac{1}{2\pi}\left| \int_{|\zeta | = r} \frac{g(\zeta) d \zeta}{(\zeta-z)^2} \right| \\
& \leq \frac{r\sqrt{r}}{r^2-|z|^2} = O\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{r}} \right) \underset{r \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0
\end{align*}

Therefore, for all complex, non-zero $z$, there exists a constant $c$, such that, $f(z)=cz^{-2}$. However if $c \neq 0$, then, the estimate $|f(z)| \leq |z|^{\frac{-3}{2}}$ is no longer true as $z$ approaches the origin. Therefore $f\equiv 0$